# Microsoft Visio Page settings

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

I used to use Visio years ago (2003 version), recently installed it again(2016 version) to make some technical drawings. But it has been frustrating to say the least.

What i wish is that the "page"  starts @ 0,0 meaning that the left top most pixel is 0.0 (like in paint). So that when i place my Rectangle @ 0,0 it ends up in the top right corner touching both borders...instead i get this :

[image]

Is there a way to adjust this?

And will the grid also adjust to start there? so i won't get this weird half grid row in front of it? like so:

[image]

I honestly don't get it that there is no default template for something as simple as this :|

Answer (score 1):

#### What I wish is that the "page" starts @ 0,0 meaning that the left top most pixel is 0.0

> **Change the position of the ruler zero point**
>
> By default, the zero point is the lower-left corner of the drawing
>   page. Do any of the following:
>
> - To change the position of the zero point on both rulers, hold down the CTRL key and, from the intersection of the two rulers, drag
>     to where you want the new zero point.
> - To change the position on one ruler, hold down the CTRL key and drag from the ruler.
> - To return the zero point to the lower-left corner of the page, double-click the intersection of the two rulers.

Source [Change the ruler measurement units in Visio - Visio](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/change-the-ruler-measurement-units-in-visio-9faf9f56-6c4c-44ac-98c2-4f942ded00ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

---

#### And will the grid also adjust to start there?

> **Change the origin of the grid**
>
> The grid origin is set to the same position as the ruler zero point.
>   If you move the ruler zero point, the grid origin also moves. You can,
>   however, set the grid origin independently from the ruler zero point.
>
> 1. On the View tab, in the Show group, click the Ruler & Grid Dialog Box Launcher.
> 2. Under Grid origin, enter x (horizontal) and y (vertical) coordinates for the point from which you want the grid to originate,
>      and then click OK.

Source [Show, hide, or change the grid in Visio - Visio](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/show-hide-or-change-the-grid-in-visio-8774ff39-c24d-4c03-a6ff-934a9e770cb9)

Comment: No way to do this with putting in numbers? because i am trying the CNTRL drag thing but holy hell what is this a pain to use :| tempting to just switch to Draw.io in terms of user friendly...

Comment: @A.bakker It would appear not, but I don't use Visio.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll hope somebody else finds something... i am really starting to dislike Office, seeing each new version adds features that are on by default that are a hell to disable :| I simply want to put some squares on a page and be able to accurately distance them...in older versions it was super easy but this is just ....so much unnecessary stuff   to " help"  you...

Comment: @A.bakker You might want to check out LibreOffice Draw :)

Comment: When i throw my house through the window i will haha :)